# octave problems with fzero when changing directory

Tags: matlab, octave

I have the following problem when I try to use fzero in Octave. If my current working directory doesn't contain any .m files, I can type

```
>> fzero("sin",1.0)
   ans = 0
```

and it works. When I change working directory to some other which has .m files (with functions), then I get the following error:

```
error: strncmpi: N must be greater than 0
error: called from
    optimget at line 39 column 7
    fzero at line 123 column 13
```

I don't understand what is this. Any ideas what's wrong?

What I was trying to do is to use fzero on some of my functions defined in .m files, and I couldn't do it (I got the error above). I narrowed down the problem as just described. I don't know why the error happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do any of your filenames conflict with built-in functions?

Comment: @Suever, yes that solved it! One of my functions had the name "length" and it conflicted with Octave's built in function. It works now, thank you very much!